# Rigging clothes to a character not working as expected

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm trying to rig clothes to a character I've made. However, it's not working as intended. I'm following this guide:

1- Select the cloth

2- Shift select the rig

3- Ctrl + P to Set parent with empty groups

4- Select the cloth Alone

5- Add the Data Transfer modifier (anywhere in the stack) then within the modifier:

6- Source object - Select your Rigged mesh (body)

7- Check Vertex Data (first in the list below Source object)

8- Select (highlight) Vertex Group(s)

9- Click Apply

10- Forget about most of your nightmares and forget about destructive solutions.

I've attached an image of what happens when I follow the above steps. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Share your file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: The steps you're describing are for body + clothes in the same pose, and I suspect that's not true of what you're showing.  Get them into the same pose first.  (Also, in general, be careful of transfer method, generate data layers with DT mod.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. That helped with one aspect of the rigging.